# On Click Paragraph to Textarea after it Update the Text in Paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });
});

function editable_text_clicked() {
  var div_text = $(this).html();
  var text_div = $("<textarea />");
  text_div.val(div_text);
  $(this).replaceWith(text_div);
  text_div.focus();
  text_div.blur(text_divBlurred);
}



function blurred(argument) {
  var html = $(this).val();
  var viewableText = $(".editable_text p");
  viewableText.html(html);
  $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
  // setup the click event for this new div
  viewableText.click(editable_text_clicked);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click( function(){
    $("editable_text").(editable_text_clicked);
  })
});
```

```css
p, textarea{
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
}
.btns{
  width:300px;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Google JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="editable_text">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum Content Comes here...
  </p>
  <div class="btns">
    <a href="#edit" class="btn btn-warning pull-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
    <a href="#update" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to Update"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm poor in JS, but sill wanted to learn it, my task for today is to create a **To Do List** , So here's what I wanted Exactly.
When I click on pencil icon, the `p` in `.editable_text` should edit, and after editing when I click on okay the text should be appended to the `p` in `.editable_text`

here's the fiddle Link, https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/nfL7qcak/8/

Answer (score 1):

Update the code as mentioned below. as user will click on edit button - textarea will show with content and as user will click on save p tag will display with content It will work, You can see here - https://jsfiddle.net/mf8wp3wf/:

```
<div class="editable_text">
<div id="dynamic-div">
  <p id="content-data">
    Lorem Ipsum Content Comes here...
  </p>
</div>

<div class="btns">
    <a href="#edit" class="btn edit-text btn-warning pull-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
    <a href="#update" class="btn update-text btn-success pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to Update"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });

  $(".edit-text").click( function(){ 
     var content = $("#content-data").html();
     $("#dynamic-div").html("<textarea id='content-area'>"+content+"</textarea>");
  });

  $(".update-text").click( function(){ 
    var text_date = $("#content-area").val();
    $("#dynamic-div").html("<p id='content-data'>"+text_date+"</p>");
  });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

a fast solution without functions. Add blurring and disable buttons onclick events.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });
});




$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#edit").click( function(){
  
  if($('.editable_text').css('display')=='block'){ 
 var text=$('.editable_text').text();
$('.editable_text').css('display','none');
$('#textarea_text').css('display','block').val(text).focus(); 
}
  })
  
$("#update").click( function(){
 
 if($('#textarea_text').css('display')=='block'){ 
  var val=$('#textarea_text').val();
$('.editable_text').css('display','block').text(val);
$('#textarea_text').css('display','none');   
}
 
 })
  


});
```

```css
p, textarea{
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
}
.btns{
  width:300px;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Google JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


   <div>
  <p class="editable_text">Lorem Ipsum Content Comes here... </p>
  <textarea id="textarea_text" style="display:none"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="btns">
<a id="edit" href="#edit" class="btn btn-warning pull-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
<a id="update" href="#update" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to Update"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: When I click on Edit i.e pen icon, the textarea should automatically focused, which is not in here your code :( @Nik Drosakis

Comment: Riot Zeast Captain, as I mentioned on my answer, that is a fast help, not a production level code or a complete solution to your case. I am working on my code simultaneously and just offer a help.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code check your console.

As for the edits, this is how you can do it:

```
$("[href='#edit']").click(function(){
    $(".editable_text").attr("contenteditable", "true").focus();
});

$("[href='#update']").click(function(){
    $(".editable_text").attr("contenteditable", "false");
});
```

[Here is ur updated **JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nfL7qcak/9/)

In my demo I identified the elements by their href attribute.
You can always add a new class to them or use unique IDs.

Also note that when you want to refer to an element by class, dont forget the *dot* infront `$(".editable_text")`

Answer (score 0):

it can be very simple, check this out:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });
});

$('#update').on('click', function(){
  $('#result').append('<li>' + $('#myText').val() + '</li>');
  $('#myText').val("").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

$('#edit').on('mouseup', function(){
  console.log( $('#myText') );
  $('#myText').attr("disabled", false).focus().select();
});
```

```css
input{
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
}
.btns{
  width:300px;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Google JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="editable_text">
  <input type='text' disabled id="myText" placeholder="Lorem Ipsum Content Comes here..."/>

  <div class="btns">
    <a href="#edit" id="edit" class="btn btn-warning pull-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
    <a href="#update" id="update" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to Update"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br>
  TODO LIST: 
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, this is little extra, but fine, here's a problem again, I cannot edit the to do Items... :(